# Set bottom CSS property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I set the bottom CSS attribute of a node in JavaScript?

As in:

```
.foo
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yourObject.style.bottom="auto|length|%|inherit"`

Taken from JavaScript and DOM reference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_bottom.asp).

Answer (score 2):

```
xxxxxx.style.bottom = "100px";
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends. In raw javascript, it will be a little different by browser. The easiest way to do that is to use something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), and then it's as easy as:

```
$('.foo').css('bottom', '100px');
```

Comment: -1 why exactly would you require a huge js library , just for doing something like this .. its stupid. And how exactly would it be differ by browser ?!

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("foo").style.bottom = "100px";
```

jQuery recommended:

```
$('.foo').css('bottom', '100px');
```